# What to do when there is duplication of column names in Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, label

I tried to create a dataframe by importing values from Excel. There is duplication of column names.
Therefore, I get .1 and .2 in the repeated columns, which I want to avoid. How is it possible?[We can see 2030.1, 2040.1, and so on in the columns whose names are repeated](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Xn9N.png)

Comment: What are you trying to do? If there are columns with the same name, python adds an extension to the column name

Comment: yes, I want to avoid that extension as it also shows up in plots. Any suggestion?

Comment: You can rename the columns - but not to a name that already exists!

Comment: But i want to plot the name of the columns without extension although they are duplicate.